# Submitting iOS App For Facebook Approval

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios7, ios8

I am trying to submit my iOS app for facebook approval since we allow users to post simultaneously to facebook using publish_actions.

I have filled out all the information, yet it still doesn't allow me to submit the app. Not sure what to do here, anyone have an insight?

[image]

Comment: You are trying to submit your App Details. Which is only needed if you want to be in App Center. If you want to submit your App Details you need to say Yes on at least one platform under App Center Listed platforms. But the easiest is just to not submit App Details

Comment: So how do I submit it without app details? Sorry, this entire process is just super vague

Comment: You remove it from the submission page